# Migrating the SQL Server Backup to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, postgresql, migration

I am just a beginner in database field. My question is how to migrate a SQL Server backup to PostgreSQL? Actually I can do this for small database, but my database backup file size is approx 125 GB. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should start by taking a look at the official documentation on [that subject](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL)

Comment: I will definitely go for the same. Thank you very much Sir..